# Python pandas: Slicing /indexing confusion

Tags: python, pandas

I am solving some model using pandas/Python. However I get some very strange results when selecting data. I suspect I am not understanding something very fundamental.

The index of the DataFrame is a pandas quarterly timeseries.

The problem is when I write:

```
data.SI_PER
```

I get the correct series:

```
2014Q1    116.832000
2014Q2    111.728001
2014Q3    106.976102
2014Q4    102.366623
2015Q1     97.849300
2015Q2     93.719593
2015Q3     89.766363
2015Q4     86.037304
```

and

```
data.SI_PER['2014Q1']
```

gives `116.83200000000002`

But when I write:

```
data.loc['2014Q1','SI_PER']
```

I get

```
0.0
```

In my understanding, the output should be the same, so clearly I am misunderstanding something.

**Edit:**

```
data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
PeriodIndex: 144 entries, 1980Q1 to 2015Q4
Columns: 2948 entries, YEAR to FIHERHVERV_NON_CRDIV_SUP
dtypes: float64(2946), int64(2)>>>
```

Comment: pls post ``data.info()``

Answer (score 2):

This is from 0.13.1, works ok

```
In [16]: df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2),index=period_range('2013',periods=10, freq='Q-JAN'),columns=['A','B'])

In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
               A         B
2013Q4 -0.905673  2.670701
2014Q1 -0.465485 -1.849802
2014Q2 -0.526230 -1.265586
2014Q3 -0.515863 -0.464663
2014Q4 -0.791347 -0.888892
2015Q1 -0.152992  0.004867
2015Q2 -0.349412 -2.581611
2015Q3  1.367116 -1.583860
2015Q4  0.837310  0.631884
2016Q1 -0.558182  0.408349

[10 rows x 2 columns]

In [18]: df.A['2014Q1']
Out[18]: -0.46548521567154932

In [19]: df.loc['2014Q1','A']
Out[19]: -0.46548521567154932
```

Comment: Thanks. So I am not wrong that it the data should be the same. Is there anything that can confuse the use of loc ?  Works on my computer as well btw.

Comment: what numpy/pandas versions?

Comment: NumPy 1.7.1, SciPy 0.12.0, Matplotlib 1.3.0, >>> pd.version.version
'0.12.0'

Comment: ahh....I do recall some of the period indexing stuff being fixed in 0.13.0....you can look at the whatsnew page http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html

Comment: Thanks, will look at it... just found out that data.loc[:,'SI_PER'] gives correct series. Only when referencing a specific index I get the problem.